# What does the time in PostgreSQL mean

Tags: postgresql

I found there are two types of time in PostgreSQL:

1. \timing: returns query execution time and the time cost to transfer data from server to client.
2. explain analyze: returns query execution time

are they correct? 
how can I see the query plan time?
in what range, the query execute time is acceptable? ms level?

thanks.

Comment: How about: 1) Test and see. 2) Ask one question at a time but put some effort into it.

Comment: thanks, I have got some results, but not sure their meaning. The explain analyze returns time much shorter than \timing, e.g., 0.317 ms vs 57.330 ms. If the time include query time is my question, however, there seems no evidence or output about it.

Comment: `\timing` will include the time it took to transfer the complete result from the server to the client. `explain analyze` only shows the time it took the query to execute on the server without sending it to the client (as explained in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html)

Comment: How about the query plan time? choosing the plan also cost some time, is it negligible comparing with time to execute query?

Comment: *Choosing*  the plan happens **always** regardless whether you run an explain or just run the statement. The `analyze` option however has an (non-trivial) overhead, again this is documented in the manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\timing is time measured on client side.

EXPLAIN ANALYZE is time measured on server side.

\timing is little bit more realistic, because result can be impacted by network transfer speed. EXPLAIN ANALYZE is less realistic, because you remove a network speed impact (what can be interesting when you investigate some strange times), but it shows detailed informations about query processing. Without any other parameters, there is significant overhead from timing measuring (it is less in recent PostgreSQL releases). When you can get more realistic time, you can use

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF) SELECT ...
```

Measured time is in milliseconds - acceptable range depends on usage - for web application is less 50ms, for desktop app less 200ms, for fast analytic less 5 seconds. But query speed usually depends on IO speed, so if you have to process 20GB table aggregation, then you cannot expect times less 100 sec (depends how big part from table have to be processed).